# Ошибка при передаче трёхмерного массива в функцию

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Draw(int arr[], const int total, const int lineMax, const int fill)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lineMax; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < fill; k++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int totalQuan = 1;
    const int lines = 10;
    const int filling = 4;

    int arr[totalQuan][lines][filling]{ //[Номер буквы][номер строки][символы]
        {
        {0, 3, 3, 3},  //{0 пусто, 1 заполнено, толщина ряда}
        {0, 2, 5, 2},
        {0, 3, 1, 3},
        {1, 3, 3, 3},
        {1, 3, 3, 3},
        {1, 9, 0, 0},
        {1, 9, 0, 0},
        {1, 3, 3, 3},
        {1, 3, 3, 3},
        {1, 3, 3, 3},
        },

    };

    Draw(arr, totalQuan, lines, filling);
}
```

Видел подобные вопросы, но не смог применить решения для своего случая.

Функция должна будет идти о трёхмерному массиву и выводить данные, логику пока ещё не писал, так как хочу сначала корректно передать данные в функцию.

Я передаю в функцию массив, при этом получаю две ошибки:

1. E0167 аргумент типа "int (*)[10Ui64][4Ui64]" несовместим с параметром типа "int *"
2. Ошибка   C2664   "void draw(int [],const int,const int,const int)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "int [10][4]" в "int []"

Comment: `void Draw(int arr[][10][4], const ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ты передаешь в массив фиксированного размера выделенный в стеке. Что бы исправить ситуацию в твоем случае нужно в функции, в принимаемых аргументах указать длину получаемого массива.

```
void Draw(int arr[1][10][4], const int total, const int lineMax, const int fill)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lineMax; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < fill; k++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Что бы избавиться от этого необходимо выделять массив динамически через ключевое слово **new**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Draw(int*** arr, const int total, const int lineMax, const int fill)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lineMax; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < fill; k++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int totalQuan = 1;
    const int lines = 10;
    const int filling = 4;

    int*** arr = new int** [totalQuan];

    for (int i = 0; i < totalQuan; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int* [lines];
        for (int j = 0; j < lines; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = new int[filling];
        }
    }

    arr[0][0][0] = 0;
    arr[0][0][1] = 3;
    arr[0][0][2] = 3;
    arr[0][0][3] = 3;
    arr[0][1][0] = 0;
    //...и так далее...

    Draw(arr, totalQuan, lines, filling);


    // не забыть удалить за собой
    for (int i = 0; i < totalQuan; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < lines; j++)
        {
            delete[] arr[i][j];
        }
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: Теперь у меня есть вопрос. Почему при передаче в функцию одномерного массива он прекрасно преобразуется в указатель на первый элемент, даже если массив выделен на стеке. А вот с двумерным уже только динамический массив нужен. Почему так? Пруфы: https://godbolt.org/z/hvnrsKW96

Comment: @ComeInRage, двумерный массив тоже преобразуется в указатель на свой первый элемент. Проблема в том, что элементами двумерного массива являются одномерные массивы. Например, массив `int arr[2][3]` преобразуется в указатель `int (*)[3]`. Вы вероятно подразумеваете, что неплохо бы было, чтобы процесс продолжался рекурсивно далее, т.е. в конечном результате получился указатель `int**`. Но так нельзя. Если разыменовать `int**` один раз, то мы должны получить указатель `int*`, но там, куда указывает `int(*)[3]` никакого указателя нет, там массив из трёх элементов типа `int`.

Comment: Компилятор должен понимать, сколько элементов пропустить, чтобы перейти к следующей строке. Поэтому одномерный можно передать без указания первой размерности как `int a[]`, а вот многомерный — только без указания первого размера, как `int arr[][10][4],`  — кстати, @banana, единичка совершенно не нужна в объявлении!